# Logging for the passthru subsystem in share

Tags: log4j, single-sign-on, alfresco, ntlm

I followed a tutorial to extend the cm:person object in Share. Essentially this involved some changes to the userprofile webscript, a UserFactory class extension and a bean referencing this class.

Since making these changes, SSO no longer works. Up till now we have used NTLM SSO from AD credentials, which was working fine. As of now, SSO still works fine for /alfresco and cifs but users are no longer automatically logged in on /share. User's can enter their AD details to log in manually.

The problem which is making this hard to troubleshoot is - I can't get any details in the log.
In the log4j properties file I have added:

```
log4j.logger.org.alfresco.smb.protocol.auth=debug
log4j.logger.org.alfresco.acegi=debug
log4j.logger.org.alfresco.passthru.auth=debug
```

When I open a folder in the CIFS share I see:

```
13:01:17,410 DEBUG [org.alfresco.smb.protocol.auth] Mapped client /192.168.1.114 to domain null
13:01:17,631 DEBUG [org.alfresco.smb.protocol.auth] Passthru sessId=10, auth ctx=[NTLM,Challenge=f93fbe68854cf0b8]
13:01:17,631 DEBUG [org.alfresco.smb.protocol.auth] Using Write transaction
13:01:17,636 DEBUG [org.alfresco.smb.protocol.auth] Setting current user using person alfresco.admin (username ChrisO)
13:01:17,636 DEBUG [org.alfresco.smb.protocol.auth] Passthru authenticate user=alfresco.admin, FULL
13:01:17,637 DEBUG [org.alfresco.smb.protocol.auth] Using Write transaction
13:01:17,640 DEBUG [org.alfresco.smb.protocol.auth] Closed auth session, sessId=10
```

When I navigate to /alfresco I see:

```
13:04:06,347 DEBUG [org.alfresco.passthru.auth] Authenticate org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.ntlm.NTLMPassthruToken@4374c52a: Username: null; Password: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: false; Details: null; Not granted any authorities via token
13:04:06,556 DEBUG [org.alfresco.passthru.auth] Passthru stage 1 token org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.ntlm.NTLMPassthruToken@4374c52a: Username: null; Password: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: false; Details: MINECORP\192.168.1.200,TCP/IP NetBIOS; Not granted any authorities
13:04:06,559 DEBUG [org.alfresco.passthru.auth] Authenticate org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.ntlm.NTLMPassthruToken@4374c52a: Username: chriso; Password: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: false; Details: MINECORP\192.168.1.200,TCP/IP NetBIOS; Not granted any authorities via token
```

But I get no output at all just for navigating to /share. When I type in my details at share's login page, all I see is:

```
13:06:56,690 DEBUG [org.alfresco.passthru.auth] Authenticate user=ChrisO via local credentials
13:06:56,690 DEBUG [org.alfresco.passthru.auth] Authenticate org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.ntlm.NTLMLocalToken@7f3384c9: Username: chriso; Password: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: false; Details: null; Not granted any authorities via token
13:06:56,903 DEBUG [org.alfresco.passthru.auth] Authenticated token=org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.ntlm.NTLMLocalToken@7f3384c9: Username: chriso; Password: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_AUTHENTICATED
```

So I am not sure what I have missed in the log4j properties. If the SSO isn't working I assume there must be some kind of problem with the request sent or the reply received, but I can't see any info about them. Is anyone aware of a different log4j target for the Share passthru subsystem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Share SSO logging, you have to adapt the log4j.properties file in the Share web application. Adapt the logger for org.alfresco.web.site.servlet.SSOAuthenticationFilter and you should see output.

Based on your log output, I would assume you have not adapted the Share configuration for SSO correctly. The output about "local credentials" shows that Share login is performed via standard login. Have you changed the configuration for "Remote" in share-config-custom.xml to use /wcs instead of /s? Have you specified  to be true?